# Does Microsoft ICE correct barrel distortion?

Tags: post-processing, panorama, lens-correction, microsoft-ice

For a panorama, I created more than a hundred images with my [Panasonic Lunix DMC FZ5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panasonic_Lumix_DMC-FZ5), with 6mm focal length (35mm equivalent: 36mm). I want to import these images into [ICE](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/groups/ivm/ICE/), to create a panorama.

The images have noticeable barrel distortion, and I could easily correct that with PTLens. Is prior correction with [PTLens](http://epaperpress.com/ptlens/) a good idea? Does ICE perhaps have a lens database itself and also do the correction? (I want to avoid double correction, naturally)

Comment: @mattdm - Do we really need a Microsoft Ice tag?

Comment: @dpollitt Why not? We have tags for other photographic software (e.g., [tag:apple-aperture], [tag:lightroom], [tag:hugin]), and this is very specifically a tag about that software.

Comment: @mattdm - It seems unnecessary for obscure software with very few questions. Even the least popular from your list has 9 questions, this just has the two questions asked by this user today. We do have the [software] tag that could use used already.http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software

Comment: @dpollitt What's the problem you're trying to address? Adding new vague tags doesn't add much value, but adding specific ones is useful even if the software is new to the site.

Comment: Also note that there was just one question about hugin when I created _that_ tag. :)

Comment: @mattdm I believe the general rule is try not to create new tags, and yes I know we aren't SO - See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18879/161501, specifically "Try to use broad tags.", and "Try not to create new tags". If you want to discuss further we can in chat or meta.

Answer (score 3):

No, MS ICE does not have a lens database AFAIK. It really does not matter much since it has to distort the images to make features match and perform blending. In my experience success is generally high but not perfect. I would try straight with ICE *first* because any processing you do before hand always adds image quality loss. If it fails, then try it after correcting. Remember that when correcting barrel distortion you loose part of the image, so there will be less overlap for MS ICE to work with.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I did the panorama already, and I ran images through PTLens prior to that. The result is OK, though not perfect, but that's most likely due to parallax error. I only had a simple travel tripod with a head that doesn't go all the way around, and so I had to move the tripod when shooting. I believe, I know to do things better next time. It was just an experiment.